# How to loop through data in Map with Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Fetched data from Firebase database and added as a Map object. now I need to loop through every key's value so I can get child data from it. here are my both Database structure and the code am using:

[image]

```java
    public void gettingStationDate() {
    // Read from the database
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("station");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            Log.e(TAG, "Value is: " + map);
            assert map != null;
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                Log.e("The Result", entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
    }
```

this code give me the result as key, value like this : `-LlRGuwBNe2-S_MHn2DW/{station_longitude=30.854333, station_name=الاصلاح الزراعى, station_latitude=29.313847, station_geohash=stjyy07mw14h}` Now what i need to do is to get the inner values of the shown values , as `statin_longitude` , `station_name` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each child node that you have is another JSON object, each value in your `Map` is another `Map`. And since all your values are strings, this time it's a `Map<String,String>`.

So to get the specific values, you'd do something like:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    assert map != null;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Log.i("The key", entry.getKey());
        Map<String,String> values = (Map<String,String>) entry.getValue();
        Log.i("station_name", map.get("station_name"));
    }
}
```

---

It is more idiomatic to use the `DataSnapshot`'s method to accomplish the same:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot stationSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        Log.i("The key", stationSnapshot.getKey());
        Log.i("station_name", stationSnapshot.child("station_name").getValue(String.class));
    }
}
```